# jenkins: Custom Checkout for a custom Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I’m having a problem with the `Jenkinsfile` syntax, using a custom *Dockerfile* without default checkout. The problem is simple: Considering the snippet below, how should I do the checkout?

When I checkout *before* the parallel stages, the checkout is done on a different node, so the Dockerfile is not found. Is that really only possible with default checkout without any custom parameters?

```
pipeline {
  options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('start parallel stages') {
      parallel {
        stage('Linux x86-64') {
          agent {
            dockerfile {
              filename 'ncp-linux.Dockerfile'
              dir 'source/tools/jenkins/docker'
              label 'docker'
            }
          }
```

I tried to checkout before the parallel stage, which results in a checkout on a different node then the node that is running docker and which is mapping its directory into the docker container.